# Different values of variable depending on its location

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I understand that variables are not block scoped and are only function scoped, so I was wondering why the variable value of `reversed` changes whether I place it inside the while loop or outside the while loop.

When `reversed` is placed inside the while loop

```
var isPalindrome = function(x) {
  if (x < 0) {
    return false;
  }
  let temp = x;
 
  while (temp > 0) {
    var reversed = 0;
    reversed = (reversed * 10) + (temp % 10);
    temp = Math.floor(temp/10);
  }
  console.log(reversed) // reversed = 1
  return reversed === x;
};

console.log(isPalindrome(121)) // false
```

When `reversed` is placed outside the while loop

```
var isPalindrome = function(x) {
  if (x < 0) {
    return false;
  }
  let temp = x;
  var reversed = 0;
  while (temp > 0) {
    reversed = (reversed * 10) + (temp % 10);
    temp = Math.floor(temp/10);
  }
  console.log(reversed) // reversed = 121
  return reversed === x;
};

console.log(isPalindrome(121)) // true
```

Comment: `var reversed = 0;` is equivalent to `var reversed; reversed = 0;` The location of the declaration with `var` in the function doesn't matter, but the location of the assignment of the value `0` does.

Comment: "*I understand that variables are not block scoped and are only function scoped*" only `var`s exhibit this behaviour, `let` and `const` are block scoped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a scoping issue. It's because you're *resetting* the `reversed` variable inside the loop every time it runs, and that affects your function's return value.